# Сбросить select

Tags: jquery, javascript

Есть 5 полей select - как при выборе обного сбросить значения другого (или вернуть в значение по умолчанию)? Попытался так но что то не работает подскажите!!!

```
if (tetra-options-select == 1) {
    $('#tetra-options-select2').val('')
};
```

Comment: Такой вариант подойдет?

    $('#tetra-options-select2').prop('selectedIndex',0);

Comment: tetra-options-select == 1 это выражение, которое JS интерпретирует как tetra минус options минус (равно ли select единице) что означает undefined

Comment: вчера на иностранном гугле ещё такой вариант нашёл
$('#name2').change(function(){
    $('#name').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});


$('#name').change(function(){
    $('#name2').prop('selectedIndex',0);
});

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('#tetra-options-select1').on('change', function(){
    var val = $(this).val();
    if (1 == val) {
        $('#tetra-options-select2').val('')
    }
});
```